# Formatting the JSON results which contain URL in Android Java

Tags: java, android, json

I consume one rest method in android asyn call and json object sample is below-

"result": 1,
    "data": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Aconitum",
        "url": "http://i1.wp.com/cottagegardenflowershop.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014"
    }

I want to format the URL like below - 
http://i1.wp.com/cottagegardenflowershop.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014

Comment: didn't understand your question can you elaborate??

Comment: Edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here use this:
lets say you receive your Json inside response String

```
String response = "result": 1, "data": [{ "id": 1, "name": "Aconitum", "url": "http://i1.wp.com/cottagegardenflowershop.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014" } 
JSONArray data = response.optJSONArray("data");
for (int i =0;i<data.length();i++){
 JSONObject jsonObject = data.getJSONObject(i);
//save this url in a list or however you want to use it
    String url = jsonObject.getString("url");
}
```